# MacHood Cinema Display Hood in US?

Tags: color-management, monitors, computer-hardware

I've been trying to find a decent monitor hood for my Apple CinemaDisplay 30", as the only place I am able to use my computer at the moment is a fairly brightly lit (during the day) area of my home. I have fully calibrated my workflow, including my screen and printer for the various papers I use. However it is extremely difficult to work during the day when it is so bright out and still keep my screen's brightness at around 180cd/m^2 or less (which makes soft-proofing prints very difficult.) I tried to create a basic makeshift hood using simple carboard, however it is rather unruly and not particularly sturdy.

I found a hood designed specifically for the CinemaDisplays, called MacHood. I've found it for sale at several European online stores, however I would like to avoid the cost of having to ship it and whatnot. I am also not thrilled about having to pay a VAT, as it appears is included at all of the stores I've looked at. Is it possible to buy this hood in the US? If not, is there a US manufacturer that makes something similar, that doesn't have a VAT tax levied on top of everything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be MacHood?

A quick google search on `apple cinema display hood` turned up [this product](http://www.photodon.com/mm5/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Product_Code=112-AC30&Store_Code=P&search=112-AC30&offset=0&filter_cat=&PowerSearch_Begin_Only_=&sort=&range_low=&range_high=).

I can't vouch for the seller or manufacturer, but according to the website, they have a 30 day money back guarantee.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily *have* to be a MacHood, although that particular one maintains the aesthetic appeal of the CinemaDisplay, which was one of the reasons I purchased it in the first place. ;)

Comment: Picky picky....

Comment: Yes, yes. That stems from the graphic/interior design aspects of my mentality. :P I like nice stuff to be nice. :D